# List flag once but input multiple files

Tags: python, docopt

```
"""
Usage:
program (--opt=OPT...) (--ano=ANO...)

Options:
  --opt=OPT    An option that can be specified multiple times to form a list
  --ano=ANO    An option that can be specified multiple times to form a list
"""

import docopt
print docopt.docopt(__doc__)
```

With the code above the following works:

```
python program.py --opt 1.txt --opt 4.txt --ano 2.txt --ano 3.txt
{'--ano': ['2.txt', '3.txt'],
 '--opt': ['1.txt', '4.txt']}
```

However, I'd like the following to work too (so that globbing is supported):

```
python program.py --opt 1.txt 4.txt --ano 2.txt 3.txt
Usage:
program (--opt=OPT...) (--ano=ANO...)
```

Like this:

```
python program --opt *.txt --ano *.csv
```

Can I achieve this with docopt?

Comment: One bad way to do this would be to accept a glob, like this: '*.csv' and get the files myself. Then I cannot use the fish shell's awesome globbing though...